# list of html attributes and its allowed types

Tags: html, web

is there any list available that maps html attribute to its allowed types, similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes ?

Example :

```
wrap : Boolean

accept : String

value : Any

tabIndex : Int
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of attributes in HTML 5: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1

The list of attributes in HTML 4: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html